# iPad - Monitor network traffic

Tags: macos, ipad, networking

I am debugging an iPad app that is running on an real iPad.

Is there a way on my Mac to monitor the router's network traffic or just the iPad's network traffic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much easier to isolate network traffic with Charles

http://www.charlesproxy.com/

Comment: Can someone please explain this in more detail? Charles is a reverse proxy that runs on desktop computers.  How does this help in capturing network traffic coming from or going to the ipad?

Comment: Ahh i see: http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/using-charles-from-an-iphone/

Answer (score 3):

Definitely use Wireshark

http://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: I encountered that I had to switch iPad's WLAN off and on again frequently in order to receive packets in my live capturing on the Mac.

Answer (score 1):

[OSX now supports packet capture](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1176/_index.html) on an attached device through their special `rvi` interface. To use it you firstly need to find UDID of the attached devices - either through Xcode or on the command line e.g.:

```
system_profiler SPUSBDataType | sed -n -E -e '/(iPhone|iPad)/,/Serial/s/ *Serial Number: *(.+)/\1/p'
```

Then use the resulting UDID in the following command to create a new associated rvi interface:

```
rvictl -s your_device_udid
```

Now one can capture packets from the i/Pad/Phone on rvi0 iface e.g.:

```
sudo tcpdump -i rvi0 -k A
```

Note: The `-k` argument is an Apple specific option, only supported in their version of tcpdump, which allows for display of additional metadata in this case it displays all metadata including interface name, process name & ID, etc. In this way one can see the traffic flowing over WiFi (en0) and Mobile (pdpX) interfaces, but not all interfaces such as ipsec0, etc.